# Como consigo que 2 hilos se alternen para imprimir por consola una cosa

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo una clase con un atributo String y en el main tengo 2 hilos uno tiene P como tributo y otro p y se trata de conseguir que salga PpPpPp por consola.

```
    public class PingPong extends Thread {

        private String word;

        public PingPong(String s) {
            word = s;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
                System.out.print(word);
                System.out.flush();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread tP = new PingPong("P");
        Thread tp = new PingPong("p");

        tp.start();
        tP.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En lo primero que debes pensar cuando necesites que dos o más hilos dependan unos de otros para realizar una tarea (en este caso ambos dependen del otro para poder escribir) es que entonces existe un recurso compartido, sino no tiene sentido. En este caso el recurso compartido es la impresora (System.out). Por lo tanto hay que sincronizar el acceso a esta y además condicionar dicho acceso a que sea el turno de imprimir de ese hilo.

Mi propuesta es que implementes una clase cuyo fin sea alternar el uso de la impresora de un tipo de hilo a otro. Para esto he hecho varios cambios a tu código.

```
public class PingPong extends Thread {

    private String word;
    private Impresora impresora;// Impresora compartido para ambos tipos de hilos
    private int tipoJugador;// Indica el tipo de hilo

    public PingPong(String s, int tipoJugador, Impresora impresora) {
        word = s;
        this.impresora = impresora;
        this.tipoJugador = tipoJugador;
    }

    public void run() {
        // El número de iteraciones lo cambié solo para probar, funciona con cualquier número
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            try {
                // En dependencia del tipo de hilo imprimo con un método o con el otro
                if (tipoJugador == 1) {
                    impresora.imprimirHilo1(word);
                } else if (tipoJugador == 2) {
                    impresora.imprimirHilo2(word);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}            
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creo el recurso compartido entre los hilos
        Impresora impresoraComun = new Impresora();

        // Creo los hilos y les defino un tipo diferente a cada uno y les paso el recurso compartido
        Thread tP = new PingPong("A", 1, impresoraComun);
        Thread tp = new PingPong("B", 2, impresoraComun);

        tp.start();
        tP.start();
    }
}

class Impresora {
    private boolean escribeHilo1 = true;

    public synchronized void imprimirHilo1(String word) throws InterruptedException {
        while (!escribeHilo1) {
            wait();
        }

        System.out.println(word);
        escribeHilo1 = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void imprimirHilo2(String word) throws InterruptedException {
        while (escribeHilo1) {
            wait();
        }

        System.out.println(word);
        escribeHilo1 = true;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Si ejecuto el programa muestra la siguiente salida

[image: Salida del programa]

Comment: Solo puedo usar las clases que tengo no puedo crear otras si puediera tener 2 clases si he visot ejemplos de crearlo

Comment: @unknow, sin un recurso compartido el cual implemente técnicas de sincronización como las que te mostré no podrás hacer lo que pides.

Comment: ya encontre como hacerlo

Comment: @unknow Perfecto! Solo que no me gusta implementar la lógica de la sincronización dentro de la misma clase del hilo. Además ten en cuenta que quizás para este caso en concreto sea útil realizar el bloqueo a nivel de la clase pero no es algo muy recomendable. De todos modos muy bien.

Answer (score -1):

Solo necesitabamos este metodo

```
public class PingPong extends Thread {

        private String word;

        public PingPong(String s) {
            word = s;
        }

        public void run() {
            synchronized (getClass()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
                    System.out.print(word);
                    System.out.flush();
                    getClass().notifyAll();
                    try {
                        getClass().wait();
                    } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                getClass().notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si funciona gracias